# how to exclude a range of ip adress when a site is access by 2 reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

We host an application (app1) that is accessed by **two** reverse proxy (apache 2.2).

- Proxy A for internet users - no rules apply
- Proxy B for corporate users (ip adresses 10.* or 160.53.*)

there are two exceptions where we want to exclude two ranges because they must use Proxy A

- 10.5.96.0/19 (mask 255.255.224.0)
- 10.126.*

So we did a RewriteRule like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app1/.*
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.126\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.5\.(9[6-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-7]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^160\.53\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://proxy2.aa.bb$1 [R]
```

So we check first for the exclusion "!^"

But when using an adress that should be excluded, it still use the Proxy B.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logic problem here. Remember that **OR** here got precence over **AND**. With the OR operator, in all languages, all members of the OR are evaluated one by one until one of them returns True (true is then returned) or until all of them are proved as False (false is returned).
Your condition comes out as:

```
if (is not in 10.126.* OR is not in 10.5.96.0/19) AND (is in 10.* OR is in 160.53.*)
```

Does it make more sense now? For all addresses in 10.*, including those you want to exclude, both the first and the second part always evaluate to True.
Just changing the first OR into an AND should do the trick.

Comment: I forgot that OR has precedence over AND !!!
Working... Thanks...